# Spark For loop for Large Tables using inner join

Tags: pyspark

Create a new table from two existing tables A & B, A has history data for 1 year and B has Data of ID's. I need to join this two tables using Spark where performance is fine as well as loop the data for each and every day or month as business_day is the partition. I cannot consider entire tables as every business day has 30 million each.

Table A - has n number of columns such as ID, Business_Day, Name

Table B - has n number of columns - ID, ID_Code

Table A should join table B using `ID=ID` and get ID_Code along with other columns of A

```
insert into output_table
select ID, ID_CODE,Business_Day, Name 
from A,B where 
A.ID=B.ID
```

I am not sure how to write For loop for the above, insert script works but for a single day it takes 2 hours and that I need to change business day manually for a year which is impossible, but a loop and other performance steps will help it run very much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spark SQL Query with Python**

[Source](http://www.alpha-epsilon.de/cca175/2017/10/07/spark-sql-with-python/)

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pandas as pd

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Table A read and spark create dataframe --> df_A
# df_A = sqlContext.createDataFrame(...)
# Table B read and spark create dataframe --> df_B
# df_B = sqlContext.createDataFrame(...)


# Example:

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        [
            [1,12,'Test'],
            [2,22,'RD']
        ],
        columns=['ID','ID_CODE','Departman']
    ))

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        [
            [1,'friday','Shan'],
            [2,'friday','ramazan'],
            [3,'friday','bozkir']
        ],
    columns=['ID','Business_Day','Name']))

### pyspark method SQL 
df = df_A.join(df_B,df_B.ID == df_A.ID)
.select('ID_CODE','Business_Day','Name')

### Spark SQL method
df1.registerTempTable('df_A')
df2.registerTempTable('df_B')

df = sqlContext.sql("""
            SELECT ID_CODE,Business_Day,Name
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM df_A A LEFT JOIN df_B B ON B.ID = A.ID
            ) df    
            """)

""").show()

[In]: df.show()
[Out]: 
+-------+------------+-------+
|ID_CODE|Business_Day|   Name|
+-------+------------+-------+
|     12|      friday|   Shan|
|     22|      friday|ramazan|
+-------+------------+-------+
```